# Dynamic Drop Down List ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu

How can I create a dynamic drop down list without using AutoPostBack. I ask because I just want to change the value of what the second drop down list displays and then the user clicks a button and it submits. But If I use AutoPostBack then it postbacks to page and runs code that shouldn't be run until that final box has been selected. (I use Postback in the other part of my program so using `!IsPostBack` isnt a option.) I looked at Javascript but ASP generates all of its controls names at runtime. What can I do? I have looked at the Ajax [CascadingDropDown](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx&ei=cvNDTuqiIanJsQLAxpDECQ&usg=AFQjCNEdHMG2A8UDJDRPY_cv2hrZ0M4_vg&sig2=wNWMfv_jmYMwzWSyZil4rg) control but my problem with that is it contained in a XML file or a Database, I need this to be contained inside my Page. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you post some code so I can see what you've got so far?

Comment: @JamesJohnson I dont have anything yet, I just began thinking about this. I did not know what way to approach this, since my first instinct was JavaScript but then after considering the fact that it would be difficult to get the actual control names i backed off from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CascadingDropDown](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) control from the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Comment: do you know of any way to use the CascadomgDropDown control without using a XML file or DB? I need all this contained within the file, adding extra files would complicate the process here.

Comment: Here's an example using a Generic List to populate the drop downs [Filling a List Using CascadingDropDown](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/filling-a-list-using-cascadingdropdown-cs)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this example](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) will help? It's part of the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit available [here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/71000).

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to get the values for the second drop down list, based on the selected value of the first. Add a `onchange` event handler on the client-side to the first drop down list that makes the AJAX call and fills the second on success.